# tool to measure performance of android app rendering time/app latency/Performance

Tags: android, performance, rendering, latency

I am an android app tester. I am looking for a tool from which i can measure app rendering time, app latency. Performance of the app?
Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Android studio`s profiler to check for your app performance. [Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler) is the link check more about profiler.

To check how much time it takes to display after views and data are fully drawn, open `Logcat` panel in Android studio and type in "**display**.

[image: TO check display time]

Moreover, you can also check how your app is performing while starting, creating views or when using the app(performing various actions).

[GPU Render profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/inspect-gpu-rendering)